# Proper Setup for Task Scheduler Task to Start Virtualbox VM at Startup

Tags: scheduled-tasks, virtualbox

I can't seem to get the file directory path working to start my VM at startup.
This would be helpful so that my home hosted server is up and running all the time.
I have a Admin account over my user account for security reasons that I also control.

My Settings:

- Run whether user is logged in or not.
- Run with highest privileges.
- Configure for: Windows10 (My OS.)

- It appears I can author as Admin or User. (Which would be appropriate? I use the user acct as daily driver)

Start Program:
Program/Script: "\?\C:Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
(The "\?" is just something I tried it doesn't work with or without it.)
argument:       startvm "NextCloud" --type gui
Start in:       C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

I attempted to test it by "Running on Demand" but I don't get a VM window and in Virtualbox it doesn't say that the VM is running.

- I think this is a file path issue or I am not giving it the correct arguments.
  Could anyone please help. I am new at controlling programs from Task Scheduler.

I've tried different file path combinations to get it right without success.
I am expecting for this Task to start a instance of vboxmanager.exe and for the argument to start one of the virtual machines I have in Virtualbox, namely: "NextCloud".

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned "Run whether user is logged in or not." so I'm guessing the VM is being ssh-ed/ RDPed into i.e. you don't need the UI element?

So instead of `--type gui` use `--type headless`

(alternatively you can just use [VBoxHeadless.exe](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless) instead of VBoxManage.exe)

HTH

Comment: I need the scheduled task I can run with operators to tell windows to open Oracle VM and then input the login information. I was following a titorial but couldn't get it to work...